# Multiplying each element of a vector with a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a vector **v** and a matrix **M**. I want to multiply each element of **v** with **M** and then sum all the resulting matrices.

```
for i=1:length(v)
    lala(:,:,i) = v(i).*M;
end
sum(lala, 3)
```

Is it possible to do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have single matrix M that don't depend from i? 
In this case sum(v(i) * M) = sum(v(i)) *M.

E.g you will have expected result for code:

```
v_sum = sum(v);
lala_sum = v_sum * M;
```

Comment: M seems to be just a numerical matrix, not a cell array of matrices, or symbolic matrices, so by the way he asked the question, M is constant with respect to the summation, hence your answer is correct.

Comment: @Danil I can't believe I missed something this obvious. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

I think Danil Asotsky's answer is correct. He's exploiting the the linearity of the operation here. I just want to give another solution, using use the Kronecker tensor product, that does not dependent on this linearity property, hence still works with operation other than `sum`:

```
kvM = kron(v,M);
result = sum(reshape(kvM,[size(M) numel(v)]),3)
```

It's too late at my local time, and I dont feel like explaining the details of why this works, if you can't figure out from matlab help and wikipedia, then comment below and I'll explain for you.